# CREATE TABLE AS select * from partitioned table

Tags: sql, oracle, database-partitioning

I want to create a  table using CTAS of partitioned table. 
New table must have all the data and partitions, subpartitions of old table.
How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first create the new table with all the partitions, there is no way you can add partition definitions to a CTAS. Once the table is created you can populate it using `insert into .. select`.

You can use `dbms_metadata.get_ddl` to get the definition of the old table.

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', 'NAME_OF_EXISTING_TABLE')
from dual;
```

Save the output of that into a script, do a search and replace to adjust the table name, then run the `create table` and then run the `insert into ... select ...`

Comment: Hi When I was surfing on Google I came across below solution, though It didn't work for me, some says it worked for them,

query:
/**
CREATE TABLE SUN_PART_EMP
PARTITION BY hash(deptno) PARTITIONS 2
AS SELECT * FROM EMP; **/

I didn't understand the meaning of the second occurrence of partition i.e PARTITIONS 2

if you understand please explain

link: https://community.oracle.com/thread/616443?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: @shriraj first part explains the partitioning scheme, second tells how many partitions to be created

Comment: Hi Satya,

my old table EMP is having two columns col_1,col_2. partition on col_1 and subpartition on coll_2. Will this be created on SUN_PART_EMP table as well? with the above code?